# libGDX: GoogleApiClient disconnected after Gdx.net.openURI

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-services, android-googleapiclient

if I called `Gdx.net.openURI("")` then I return into the game, the `GoogleApiClient` disconnected. Why??

```
if (event.getTarget().getName().equals("facebook")) {
    Gdx.net.openURI("https://www.facebook.com/*****");
}
```

Comment: You may try to use the method that:`GoogleApiClient.connect()` when you need to  connect again. See here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#connect()

Comment: uh, I didn't found it method `connect()` from `GoogleApiClient` in my code. I built client only. So, When I called `connect()` after building client, the problem has gone. so, I don't need to call `connect()` method again after `Gdx.net.openURI("");`. Thanx a lot @bjiang for this replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As our discussed above:

Try to use the method that `GoogleApiClient.connect()`.

For more details, please refer here:

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#connect()